# Keras: how to reshape last channel into squares

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, keras-layer

I have an input layer of size 32x32. Then I apply a 2d convolution with stride (4,4) and with 16 filters each having kernel size 4x4. Hence, the resulting shape will be 8 x 8 x 16. Now I want to reshape the result back to the input shape so that the channel dimension will turn back into 4x4 squares in the corresponding places, i.e. if we define the result of the convolution as `T` and the desired result as `D`, then I want `D[i * 4 + k, j * 4 + l] = T [i , j , k * 8 + l]`, with i,j = 0,..,7 and k,l = 0,..,3. Is there a way to do this?

```
import numpy as np
from keras.layers import Input, Conv2D
from keras.initializers import Constant

input = Input(( 32, 32), dtype = 'float32') 

filters = np.ndarray((4, 4, 16), dtype=np.float32)
# Initialization of the filter

filter_layer = Conv2D(16, 4, strides =(4,4), kernel_initialzer=Constant(filters), trainable = False)(input)

# no idea  how to reshape the filter back
```

Comment: `Conv2DTranspose` should be what you're looking for: https://keras.io/layers/convolutional/#conv2dtranspose

Comment: Could not figure out how it works. Instead, I  reshaped the filter_layer to shape ( 8,8,4,4) then called K.premute_dimensions(reshaped_filter_layer, (0,1,3,2,4)) and than reshaped it back to size (32,32).